# @Value annotation is not working in my model class

Tags: java, spring

I have configured a Url in *application-local.properties* file and I have used @Value annotation in my model class to fetch the Url and returning it in one of the methods in the same model class.

```
gde.rateprint.endpoint.url=https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv
```

above changes I have made in property file and below changes are from model class.

```
@Value("${gde.rateprint.endpoint.url}")
private String ratePrintUrlCsv;


public String getRatePrintUrlCsv(){
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(ratePrintUrlCsv)){
        return ratePrintUrlCsv;
    }
    return null;
}
```

In my case when I'm try to get it in model class it is always returning null, but I have observed same approach is working in other Classes. So what could be missing here?

Note: Also property file is in the different directory in both cases.

Sorry for my bad explanation but if anyone faced similar issue pls help!!

Comment: Do you have any Annotations on class-level such a @Component or @Service?

Comment: yes I am using @Component annotation here

Comment: Can you please make sure that the imports  in the model class for Value annotation are of correct type?

Comment: that is correct, I double checked

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, see this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) and this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class RatePrintUrlTest {

    @Autowired
    private RatePrintUrl ratePrintUrl;

    @Test
    void getRatePrintUrlCsv() {
        assertNotNull(ratePrintUrl);
        assertEquals("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv", ratePrintUrl.getRatePrintUrlCsv());
    }
}
```